# 240GB SSD is only shown as 32KB device

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have a Mushkin Chronos 240GB SSD that used to contain a NTFS partition with windows installed. This morning the Bios started to report that no os could be found when turning the computer on.

I tried with windows recovery without luck. The only thing that I have changed in the drive is writing a new mbr using `bootrec /fixmbr` in windows recovery.

I then switched to linux to see if I could find anything suspicious there about the drive. However it is always listed as a 32KB drive.

The output of `fdisk` for that drive is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 32 KiB, 32768 bytes, 64 sectors
Disk model: SandForce{200026
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

`ddrescue` will only copy the 32KB when using it like this:

```
sudo ddrescue /dev/sda /media/ubuntu/Extern/ssd.img /media/ubuntu/Extern/status.log
```

Is there some way to access the rest of the data contained in the drive?

**EDIT**

output of gpart is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo gpart /dev/sda

Begin scan...
End scan.

Checking partitions...
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

**EDIT2:**

output of `lsblk /dev/sda` is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0  32K  0 disk
```

**EDIT3:**

output of `smartctl`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.13.0-30-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SandForce{200026BB}
Serial Number:    1
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00232d 000000001
Firmware Version: 402ABBR0
User Capacity:    32,768 bytes [32.7 KB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Mon Mar 14 14:49:17 2022 UTC
SMART support is: Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

Adding `-T permissive` does not show any more details.

**EDIT4:**

I just found a similiar issue reported here: https://linustechtips.com/topic/1001108-33kb-200026bb-recovery-sandforce-help/ - seems to confirm the drive is dead.

Comment: Sounds like the drive has died.

Comment: That or something happened with what you did? Why exactly did you do that? Any preinstalled Windows is uEFI and GPT, not MBR. And even if you had it installed in Legacy mode, hence MBR (for reasons?), why would you be writing a new MBR? What problems were you trying to solve? In any case this isn't an Ubuntu question, you're usage of it here is incidental.

Comment: @Frobozz I added the output

Comment: @ChanganAuto But as far as I understood I should be able to access the data on the drive using tools like `ddrescue` and `gpart`. So actually it shouldn't matter too much what I did with windows recovery before as long as I didn't overwrite the whole drive, which I didn't.

Comment: You should check the disk's S.M.A.R.T. info. Your drive is probably dead. You can also try to plug the drive to another computer and check it once more there.

Comment: @Frobozz Ubuntu is started from a usb stick without installation.

Comment: Ah, Let's try @FedKad's suggestion: `smartctl --scan`

Comment: If you get a list of drives with that, and can identify your Mushkin, you can check it's health with: `smartctl --all /dev/sd ...`

Comment: Not necessarily.  Early SSD's SMART support totally sucked - I remember getting that exact message on brand new drives I was installing.  We need to run filesystem checks on each of the partitions on Mushkin - I will post syntax later today.

Answer (score 1):

The sandforce controller has a bug which bricks it.
I found a guide that is quite long that will make it working but lose the data. Sadly the guide requires you to figure out the model of the memory bank but in my chronos CR240GB-DX7 the memory banks were unmarked.

https://computerlounge.it/how-to-unbrick-sandforce-ssd/